# Excel application in Word doesn't close

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've tried all the ways to close the application but stay in the opened in background in the task manager

`Dim appXL As Object, fileXL As Object, nameXlFile, filePath As String
    filePath = file_dir & "\" & file_name
    Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = False
    Set fileXL = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=filePath , ReadOnly:=True)
    ......`

```
appXL.quit 
set appXL = Nothing
```

Comment: Did you try commenting out appXL.Visible = False, or setting it to True at the end? Maybe there is a Dialog Window asking something.

Comment: are you closing the workbook before quitting, was it found?  also, the `....` could be the issue, so may be post more fuller code to.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I tried and not by any message

Comment: I tryed also to open and close immediatly without the "......" but doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern happens when you automate Excel from another VBA application and you use non-qualified Excel Objects. Kind of, it obliges the VBA runtime to create a hidden/dummy reference on the object's parent.

You have to be extremely specific using Excel objects through automation. Excel becomes *less tolerant* toward non-qualified objects when driven from another application. **Qualify everything**. Start with

```
Set fileXL = appXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=filePath , ReadOnly:=True)
'           ^^^^^^^
```

and make sure every Excel object inside your code is fully qualified.

Also, it is better to make the Excel application visible if you can, to observe what is happening. It occurs sometimes that it is displaying an alert for some reason, i.e. a non-saved workbook. These alerts can be disabled with

```
appXL.DisplayAlerts = False
```

which is useful as well, but making your appXL visible is useful at least during the development phase of your application, until you get fairly comfortable with it.

p.s.
I tested your code in MS-Word with and without the explicit `appXL.` qualification, removing everything else in the `......`. Without the qualification, Excel's instance remained in the task manager. With the qualification, it disappeared.

Comment: I tried to use:
`Set fileXL = appXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=filePath , ReadOnly:=True)
appXL.quit `
And open an empty document for security.... I am going crazy :(

Comment: @CeccoBeppe I tested your code in MS-Word with and without the `appXL.` explicit qualification, removing everything else in the `......`. Without the qualification, Excel's instance remained in the task manager. With the qualification, it disappeared. You might be facing a different issue as of now. Could you be more clear about what's the new issue?

Comment: What I meant was that I put the qualification and tried it on a virgin excel file 'visible = true'.
Unfortunately, they stay on the task manager

Comment: Did you omit everything else and test only tthe few shown lines? As I said you may have some unqualified objects in the rest of the code..

Comment: i tried this code now:

`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim appXL As Object, fileXL As Object, nameXlFile, filePath As String
filePath = "C:\Users\Public\Test\Test.xlsx"
Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appXL.Visible = True
Set fileXL = appXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=filePath, ReadOnly:=True)

appXL.Quit

End Sub`

Comment: This code works perfectly for me and kills completely the Excel Application. I'm trying to figure out what could be going wrong in your environment. BTW did you refresh the task manager?

Comment: Really many thanks for you and for other users who have helped me.
I had to wait about half a minute to upgrade the task manager.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the following where you have written ".....":

```
fileXL.Close False
```

This forces the file to be closed before you exit the application.

I believe that Excel asks you if you want to save your workbook (even that it's opened as Readonly). This keeps Excel open/active after you exit your routine, but you can't see it.

The complete code should be like this:

```
Sub OpenExcelWorkbook()
    Dim appXL As Object, fileXL As Object, nameXlFile, filePath As String

    filePath = file_dir & "\" & file_name
    Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = False
    Set fileXL = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=filePath , ReadOnly:=True)

    ' Do additional/optional stuff with your workbook here...

    fileXL.Close False ' Close the workbook without saving

    appXL.quit 
End Sub
```

Comment: It's very unlikely that the issue at hand is due to not closing the workbook, because it was open in `ReadOnly:=True` mode.

Comment: Actually it's not unlikely. When you open a workbook in readonly mode you can still modify it. After modification Excel will ask the user if the changes should be saved (but as a new document though). If the workbook has formulas that are calculated automatically at start, then the workbook will be "modified" and a (hidden) prompt for saving changes will appear. This prevents Excel from quitting properly, since the application waits for user response...

Comment: Yes this is a possible scenario. By unlikely I meant that the "......" code is unlikely to make changes to the WB. But yeah there's the possibility that the WB has external links. Likely or unlikely, that is the question :P

Answer (score 2):

Can you try like this:

```
Dim appXL As Object, fileXL As Object, nameXlFile, filePath As String
filePath = file_dir & "\" & file_name
Set appXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
appXL.Visible = False
Set fileXL = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=filePath , ReadOnly:=True)

fileXL.Save
fileXL.Close
```

You do not need the `set appXL = Nothing`, because `appXL` is a variable within the scope of the 
current procedure and the "garbage collector" would take care of it.